# css background doesn't stretch with modal box content

Tags: css, simplemodal

I have changed a css file for a modal login window/popup. The problem was that when I used the login form, I have some scrollbars at the under and on the right side. I came up with the idea to stretch the login dialog to make it all wider and heigher. The problem now is that the background doesn't stretch with the new dimentions.

**The height and the width was originally 100%**

```
#sbox-content
{
    clear:                  both;
    overflow:               auto;
    background-color:       #fff;
    height:                 130%;
    width:                  160%;
}
```

This is the complete css file, can somebody explain me what and where to edit to make the background, fit the new dimentions? Maybe there is a better sollution without having to set the original 100% sizes to 130% and 160%

```
.body-overlayed embed, .body-overlayed object, .body-overlayed select
{
    visibility:             hidden;
}

#sbox-window embed, #sbox-window object, #sbox-window select
{
    visibility:             visible;
}

#sbox-overlay
{
    position:               absolute;
    background-color:       #FFFFFF;
}

#sbox-window
{
    position:               absolute;
    background-color:       #FF7400;
    text-align:             left;
    overflow:               visible;
    padding:                5px;
    -moz-border-radius:     3px;
}

* html #sbox-window
{
    top: 50% !important;
    left: 50% !important;
}

#sbox-btn-close
{
    position:               absolute;
    width:                  30px;
    height:                 30px;
    right:                  -120px;
    top:                    -15px;
    background:             url(../images/closebox.png) no-repeat top left;
    border:                 none;
}

.sbox-loading #sbox-content
{
    background-image:       url(../images/spinner.gif);
    background-repeat:      no-repeat;
    background-position:    center;
}

#sbox-content
{
    clear:                  both;
    overflow:               auto;
    background-color:       #fff;
    height:                 130%;
    width:                  160%;
}

.sbox-content-image#sbox-content
{
    overflow:               visible;
}

#sbox-image
{
    display:                block;
}

.sbox-content-image img
{
    display:                block;
}

.sbox-content-iframe#sbox-content
{
    overflow:               visible;
}
```

Comment: Argh, I think I misread your question. I thought you were looking to resize a background image. Sorry. I deleted my answer so the question shows up unanswered in the list again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *sure* I understand the question, but perhaps you just need:

```
#sbox-content
{
    clear:              both;
    overflow:           hidden;
    background-color:   #fff;
    height:             auto;
    width:              auto;
}
```

Could you clarify with a working test-case online?

EDIT

Thanks for clarifying.

Seems you should increase the size of the modal window when you call it:

```
$("#sample").modal({
    minHeight:400,
    minWidth: 600
});
```

Comment: www.friesecomputerservice.nl and on the left side there is a Log-In link.

Comment: :auto is not working for the height and I think it will give problems for the closebox.png because it's a absolute position, but that would be a problem for later concern.

Comment: I have no idea where to put this. Do you know where?